# create keypair in hardware backed android keystore

Tags: android

I'm using samsung galaxy s7 and checked it's support hardware-backed keystore. (Settings->Security->Credential storage->Storage type)

Then, I tried to generate a new private key and check with KeyInfo's isInsideSecureHardware, but it returns false. And I found a set of keystore related files are generated at '/data/misc/keystore/user_0/' directory.

Why the key not stored in hardware(TEE)? and how to generate a key in hardware secure keystore?

Here is my code:

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(this.algorithm, "AndroidKeyStore");
Builder kpgparams = (new Builder(keyname, 6)).setAlgorithmParameterSpec(new ECGenParameterSpec(this.curve)).setDigests(new String[]{"SHA-256"}).setUserAuthenticationRequired(false).setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(300);
kpg.initialize(kpgparams.build());
KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
:
KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance(privateKey.getAlgorithm(), "AndroidKeyStore");
KeyInfo keyInfo = factory.getKeySpec(privateKey, KeyInfo.class);
boolean secure = keyInfo.isInsideSecureHardware();
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: have you got the answer, If yes can you please post it.

Comment: @a.m. please see below answer. It may help you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Android, how to ensure that Private Key is stored inside secure hardware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38178683/in-android-how-to-ensure-that-private-key-is-stored-inside-secure-hardware)

Answer (score 1):

I could see differences on how you create a key. I have created key as below.

```
public static boolean createKey(Context context) {
    try {
        // Create new key if needed
        if (!isKeyPresent()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Creating new KEY. KEY ALIAS NOT FOUND");
            Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
            end.add(Calendar.YEAR, 10);
            KeyPairGeneratorSpec spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(context)
                    .setAlias(KEY_ALIAS)
                    .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=" + KEY_ALIAS + ", O=Android Authority"))
                    .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
                    .setStartDate(start.getTime())
                    .setEndDate(end.getTime())
                    .build();
            KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", KEYSTORE_TYPE);
            generator.initialize(spec);
            generator.generateKeyPair();
            return true;
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "KEY ALIAS Exists");
            return false;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then verified the whether the device has hardware-backed-keystore as below.

```
public static boolean isHardwareBackedKeyStore() {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
        return KeyChain.isBoundKeyAlgorithm(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA);
    } else {
        try {
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_TYPE);
            keyStore.load(null);
            PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(KEY_ALIAS, null);
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(privateKey.getAlgorithm(), "AndroidKeyStore");
            KeyInfo keyInfo = keyFactory.getKeySpec(privateKey, KeyInfo.class);
            return keyInfo.isInsideSecureHardware();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

where the constants used being

```
private static final String TAG = "KeyStoreHelper";
private static final String KEY_ALIAS = "MyApp_Key_Alias";
private static final String CIPHER_TYPE = "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding";
private static final String KEYSTORE_TYPE = "AndroidKeyStore";
```

This check is working fine for me. This may help you.

Note: You might have already got some better solution. If so, please post it here.