# What Is the Difference Between isInsideSecureHardware() and isUserAuthenticationRequirementEnforcedBySecureHardware()?

Tags: android, android-keystore

Android 6.0+ has a `KeyInfo` class to get info on a key saved in the `AndroidKeyStore`. On the `KeyInfo` class, we have `isInsideSecureHardware()` and `isUserAuthenticationRequirementEnforcedBySecureHardware()` methods. We also have `isUserAuthenticationRequired()`. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyInfo.html), as usual, sucks.

Based on method names and the (limited) documentation, it would seem as though `isUserAuthenticationRequirementEnforcedBySecureHardware()` is simply a logical AND of 
`isInsideSecureHardware()` and `isUserAuthenticationRequired()`.

Is there something more to it than that? If so, what does it mean for the user authentication requirement to be enforced by secure hardware, beyond just the key being in secure hardware?

Comment: _"As an additional security measure, for keys whose key material is inside secure hardware, **some** key use authorizations **may** be enforced by secure hardware, depending on the Android device. Cryptographic and user authentication authorizations are **likely** to be enforced by secure hardware. Temporal validity interval authorizations are unlikely to be enforced by the secure hardware because it normally does not have an independent secure real-time clock."_ ([source](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore)).

Comment: I interpret that as `isUserAuthenticationRequirementEnforcedBySecureHardware` **not** simply being a logical AND of `isInsideSecureHardware` and `isUserAuthenticationRequired`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method `isUserAuthenticationRequirementEnforcedBySecureHardware()` is not a logical AND of `isInsideSecureHardware()` and `isUserAuthenticationRequired()`.

But if you dig into the [code](http://androidxref.com/8.1.0_r33/xref/frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/keystore/AndroidKeyStoreSecretKeyFactorySpi.java#172), you can see that it is a logical AND of 3 things:

1. isUserAuthenticationRequired()
2. 0 SW Enforced User Authenticators
3. 1 or more HW Enforced User Authenticators

Snippet of code:

```
boolean userAuthenticationRequirementEnforcedBySecureHardware = (userAuthenticationRequired)
                && (keymasterHwEnforcedUserAuthenticators != 0)
                && (keymasterSwEnforcedUserAuthenticators == 0);
```

The difference is not whether the key is secure in hardware, but if user authentication is backed by hardware, not software. For most, if not all devices with fingerprint readers, user authentication in secure hardware means the TEE would contain two things that interact with the Keymaster Trusted App:

1. [Gatekeeper](https://source.android.com/security/authentication/gatekeeper) Trusted App for pin/password/pattern
2. [Fingerprint](https://source.android.com/security/authentication/fingerprint-hal) Trusted App for fingerprint authentication

Example scenarios:

- `isUserAuthenticationRequirementEnforcedBySecureHardware()` could return **false** if both `isInsideSecureHardware()` and `isUserAuthenticationRequired()` return true, but the user authentication is done in SW and not in the TEE. (not likely)
- `isUserAuthenticationRequirementEnforcedBySecureHardware()` could return **true** if  `isInsideSecureHardware()` returns false (key is not supported in device's secure hardware) and `isUserAuthenticationRequired()` returns true with the user authentication done in HW. (possible)

Answer (score 2):

> isUserAuthenticationRequirementEnforcedBySecureHardware() is simply a logical AND of isInsideSecureHardware() and isUserAuthenticationRequired().

I think that's not true (see methods below) it comes via the `key` from `KeyChain`.

> Is there something more to it than that?

[KeyInfo.java](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/keystore/java/android/security/keystore/KeyInfo.java) 
is a container class for `key` info from a `KeyChain`.
Whether the `key` is bound to the secure hardware is known only *once* the `key` has been imported.

To find out, use:

```
{
    PrivateKey key = ...; // private key from KeyChain

    KeyFactory keyFactory =
        KeyFactory.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm(), "AndroidKeyStore");
    KeyInfo keyInfo = keyFactory.getKeySpec(key, KeyInfo.class);
    if (keyInfo.isInsideSecureHardware()) 
    {
        // The key is bound to the secure hardware of this Android
    }
}
```

From [KeyInfo.java](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/keystore/java/android/security/keystore/KeyInfo.java):

```
/**
 * Returns {@code true} if the key resides inside secure hardware (e.g., Trusted Execution
 * Environment (TEE) or Secure Element (SE)). Key material of such keys is available in
 * plaintext only inside the secure hardware and is not exposed outside of it.
 */
public boolean isInsideSecureHardware() 
{
    return mInsideSecureHardware;
}

/**
 * Returns {@code true} if the requirement that this key can only be used if the user has been
 * authenticated is enforced by secure hardware (e.g., Trusted Execution Environment (TEE) or
 * Secure Element (SE)).
 *
 * @see #isUserAuthenticationRequired()
 */
public boolean isUserAuthenticationRequirementEnforcedBySecureHardware() 
{
    return mUserAuthenticationRequirementEnforcedBySecureHardware;
}

/**
 * Returns {@code true} if the key is authorized to be used only if the user has been
 * authenticated.
 *
 * <p>This authorization applies only to secret key and private key operations. Public key
 * operations are not restricted.
 *
 * @see #getUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds()
 * @see KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder#setUserAuthenticationRequired(boolean)
 * @see KeyProtection.Builder#setUserAuthenticationRequired(boolean)
 */
public boolean isUserAuthenticationRequired() 
{
    return mUserAuthenticationRequired;
}
```

See also:
 [KeyStore.java](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/keystore/java/android/security/KeyStore.java)

Comment: That shows three separate fields in `KeyInfo`. It does not indicate whether those three fields are indeed independent (it would be based on whatever is calling the constructor). Also, it does not explain what it means for the user authentication requirement to be enforced by secure hardware, beyond just the key being in secure hardware. Thanks, though!

Comment: Yes, as I said **KeyInfo.java** is a *container class* for *key* info from a *KeyChain*, and so it's methods are a simple relay of data from the constructor. I'm not saying how the data to the constructor was formed, I'm saying your *contention* that a "simply a logical AND" is *inferred* anywhere in documentation or the code I have displayed, is misplaced (at least to me). I guess I have to look further for the constructorcaller...but **secure hardware is known only once the key has been imported** hmm pondering, and why have the field if it can be reconstructed  (I would not do it that way)?

Comment: @CommonsWare I have in the course of my research on the subect come across the comment that some of these methods return *different results* on *multiple calls* on the *same device*, which *if true* is very *puzzling* and  *extremely worrisome* about the integrity of the code..

Answer (score 1):

> isUserAuthenticationRequirementEnforcedBySecureHardware() is simply a
>   logical AND of isInsideSecureHardware() and
>   isUserAuthenticationRequired().

From the given documentation   isUserAuthenticationRequirementEnforcedBySecureHardware method must not be logical AND of above two methods.

For observation purpose you can consider this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38178683/in-android-how-to-ensure-that-private-key-is-stored-inside-secure-hardware) question, answer and comments.

Comment: "must not be logical AND of above two methods" -- and your proof of this is... what, exactly? And, if you do have proof, what does it mean for the user authentication requirement to be enforced by secure hardware, beyond just the key being in secure hardware? "For observation purpose you can consider this link question, answer and comments" -- none of that addresses this question.